# impossibility of using useContext in appWithTranslation next-i18next

Tags: reactjs, next.js, i18next

I'm trying to upgrade from `next-intl to next-i18next`, the problem is that when I wrap my root  layout using appWithTranslation I get an error that the component uses `useContext` and in server components you can't do that, I can't figure out how to get around this problem

> "next": "13.4.3",
> "next-i18next": "^15.2.0",

[image: Error img]

I really don't understand what's wrong since I'm doing everything according to the documentation

My root  layout

```
const inter = Inter({
  subsets: ['latin'],
});

const generateStaticParams = (): [{ locale: string }, { locale: string }] => [{ locale: 'en' }, { locale: 'pl' }];

interface LocaleLayoutProps {
  children: ReactNode;
  params: {
    locale: string;
  };
}

const LocaleLayout: ({ params: { locale }, children }: LocaleLayoutProps) => Promise<JSX.Element> = async ({
  params: { locale },
  children,
}): Promise<JSX.Element> => {
  console.log(locale);

  return (
    <html lang={locale}>
      <head>
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/icons/favicon.ico" />
      </head>
      <body className={inter.className}>
        <ReduxProvider>
          <PageWrapper>{children}</PageWrapper>
          <LogoutOnTabClose />
        </ReduxProvider>
      </body>
    </html>
  );
};

export { generateStaticParams };

export default appWithTranslation(LocaleLayout);
```

In-app folder I keep folders [locale] and store

Comment: Consider https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors to also include the error as text